# Array of subarrays of objects, how to not modify original array in function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In a small program I wrote I have an array with 3 subarrays each holding 4 objects. I put the array through a function that eliminates values from each subarray until there is only 1 object in each subarray left, and it returns an object containing the last 3 remaining objects.

My problem is that the original array is modified in the process no matter what I do. I have tried the following:

```
    var itemsArr = [[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4], [moreObj1, moreObj2, moreObj3, moreObj4],[lastObj1, lastObj2, lastObj3, lastObj4]];

    // each item in itemsArr subjarrays are objects containing name, url, and id keys.

        var generateResults = function(array, num){
        var arr = array.slice();    // generating copy of original array here (for some reason it isn't working 
// have also tried arr = [].concat(array);
        var counter = 1;
        var holderObj;
        var results = {
          baby: null,
          husband: null,
          home: null
        };
        var tempArr;
        // iterate over outer array, containing arrays in each element
        var i = 0;
        while (true){
            if (arr[i].length === 1){
                holderObj = arr.splice(i,1)[0][0];
                i--; // accounting for reindexing of arr. could also iterate backwards if this doesn't work
                results[holderObj.id] = holderObj;
            }
            if (arr[i]){
                for (var j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
                    if (counter === num){
                        arr[i].splice(j,1);
                        counter = 0;
                        j--;  // accounts for reindexing of arr[i]. Other solution would be iterating backwards
                    }
                    else{
                        counter ++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (results.baby !== null && results.husband !== null && results.home !== null){
              break;
            }
            else if (i === arr.length-1){
                i = -1;
            }

            i++;
        }
        return results;
    }
```

how can i prevent my original itemsArr from being modified when i call generateResults(itemsArr, num);?

I have also tried replacing the first line of generateResults with 
var arr = [].concat(array);

Comment: [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s `_.cloneDeep()`?

Comment: arr.splice(j,1);
seems to be where original subarrays are being modified - both arr - the sliced copy of the array parameter - and the array parameter itself still contain the same (sub) Array object values.

Comment: correction: that should read `arr[i].splice(j,1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.slice()`

`generateResults(itemsArr.slice(), num)`

```js
var itemsArr = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4}];
var itemsArrCopy = itemsArr.slice();
itemsArrCopy.splice(1,1);
console.log(itemsArr, itemsArrCopy);
```

Comment: i have been trying 
var itemsArrCopy = itemsArr.slice(); // and I have tried
var itemsArrCopy2 = [].concat(itemsArr); 

both of which don't protect my original array when they go through the generate results function

Comment: @jmancherje _"have been trying var itemsArrCopy = itemsArr.slice();"_ Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net where `var itemsArrCopy = itemsArr.slice();` modifies `itemsArr` ?

Answer (score 0):

A two level array copy should prevent modifying the array of arrays `array`parameter, by replacing

```
var arr = array.slice();
```

with

```
var arr = [];
// ...
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    arr[i] = array[i].slice();
```

As posted the copy of `array` makes `arr` and `array` different Array objects but leaves their elements the same Arrays.  So `arr[i].splice(j,1);` in the posted code is modifying `array[i]` because it is the same array as `arr[i]`